# In Sword & Sworcery, does this number sequence mean anything?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

I think it was during the final cutscene

> after reassembling the trigon in the grove.

A distorted voice can be heard saying a number sequence "4086340...86" (I didn't quite catch it completely). Is there any significance to this number or is it random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a phone number which you can call.

There is a great deal of discussion and speculation about it in this [Steam thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2683422).

You can also listen to the recording [here](http://www.whatsupmann.com/2011/04/swords-sworcery-voicemail/), although apparently the message has changed over time.